# Const is not defined -> Yet standard solutions don't work

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to display a [mapped list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN3Qo.png) where "UserName" is an entry value from a Firebase Realtime Database corresponding to the author of each entry.

The following code, inside the `get(UsernameRef).then((snapshot) =>{})` scope, returns an undefined reference error as expected, `'UserName' is assigned a value but never used` and `'UserName' is not defined`

```
  const [RecipeLibrary, setRecipeLibrary] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const RecipeLibraryRef = ref(db, "Recipes/");
    onValue(RecipeLibraryRef, (snapshot) => {
      const RecipeLibrary = [];
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        const AuthorUserId = child.key;

        child.forEach((grandChild) => {
          const UserNameRef = ref(db, "Account/" + AuthorUserId + "/username");
          get(UserNameRef).then((snapshot) => {
            const UserName = snapshot.val();
          });
          RecipeLibrary.push({
            name: grandChild.key,
            author: UserName,
            ...grandChild.val(),
          });
        });
      });
      setRecipeLibrary(RecipeLibrary);
      console.log({ RecipeLibrary });
    });
  }, []);
```

I've tried:

- Using a React state to pass the variable -> Can't use inside React useEffect
- Exporting and Importing a separate function that returns the desired UserName -> return can only be used in the inner scope
- Moving the list .push inside the Firebase get scope -> React.useState can no longer access the list

I'm hoping there is a simple solution here, as I am new.
Your time and suggestions would mean a lot, thank you!

**Update:**

I got the `RecipeLibrary` array to contain the desired "UserName" entry, named `author` by moving the array .push inside the .then scope. [Here is a log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A2Pn.png) of that array at set (line 59) and at re-render (line 104).

```
    child.forEach((grandChild) => {
      const UserNameRef = ref(db, "Account/" + AuthorUserId + "/username");
      get(UserNameRef).then((snapshot) => {
        const UserName = snapshot.val();
        RecipeLibrary.push({
          name: grandChild.key,
          author: UserName,
          authorId: AuthorUserId,
          ...grandChild.val(),
        });
      });
    });
  });
  setRecipeLibrary(RecipeLibrary);
  console.log(RecipeLibrary);
```

However, now the mapped list is [not rendering at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOToN.png) on screen.

Just some added context with minimal changes to original code, been stuck on this so long that I'm considering a full re-write at this point to jog my memory. Oh and here is the bit that renders the mapped list in case:

```
<Box width="75%" maxHeight="82vh" overflow="auto">
            {RecipeLibrary.map((RecipeLibrary) => (
              <Paper
                key={RecipeLibrary.name}
                elevation={3}
                sx={{
```

etc...

Comment: Let me know if there are any issues with the approaches suggested! It's best to give feedback so users of the site can tell whether a question has been resolved, or if a new answer is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one - the plainest option might be to move `push()` *and* `setRecipeLibrary()` inside the `then()` callback so they're all within the same scope, but that would have some terrible side effects (for example, triggering a re-render for every recipe retrieved).

The goal (which you've done your best to achieve) should be to wait for all the recipes to be loaded first, and then use `setRecipeLibrary()` to set the full list to the state. Assuming that `get()` returns a Promise, one way to do this is with `await` in an async function:

```
const [RecipeLibrary, setRecipeLibrary] = React.useState([]);
React.useEffect(() => {
  const RecipeLibraryRef = ref(db, "Recipes/");
  onValue(RecipeLibraryRef, (snapshot) => {

    // An async function can't directly be passed to useEffect(), and
    // probably can't be accepted by onValue() without modification,
    // so we have to define/call it internally.
    const loadRecipes = async () => {
      const RecipeLibrary = [];

      // We can't use an async function directly in forEach, so
      // we instead map() the results into a series of Promises
      // and await them all.
      await Promise.all(snapshot.docs.map(async (child) => {
        const AuthorUserId = child.key;

        // Moved out of the grandChild loop, because it never changes for a child
        const UserNameRef = ref(db, "Account/" + AuthorUserId + "/username");

        // Here's another key part, we await the Promise instead of using .then()
        const userNameSnapshot = await get(UserNameRef);
        const UserName = userNameSnapshot.val();

        child.forEach((grandChild) => {    
          RecipeLibrary.push({
            name: grandChild.key,
            author: UserName,
            ...grandChild.val(),
          });
        });
      }));
      
      setRecipeLibrary(RecipeLibrary);
      console.log({ RecipeLibrary });
    };

    loadRecipes();
  });
}, []);
```

Keep in mind that `Promise.all()` isn't *strictly* necessary here. If its usage makes this less readable to you, you could instead execute the grandChild processing in a plain for loop (not a forEach), allowing you to use `await` without mapping the results since it wouldn't be in a callback function.

If `snapshot.docs` isn't available but you can still use `snapshot.forEach()`, then you can convert the Firebase object to an Array similar to [Convert A Firebase Database Snapshot/Collection To An Array In Javascript](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2017/05/convert-firebase-database-snapshotcollection-array-javascript/):

```
// [...]

      // Change this line to convert snapshot
      // await Promise.all(snapshot.docs.map(async (child) => {
      await Promise.all(snapshotToSnapshotArray(snapshot).map(async (child) => {

// [...]

// Define this somewhere visible
function snapshotToSnapshotArray(snapshot) {
    var returnArr = [];

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        returnArr.push(childSnapshot);
    });

    return returnArr;
}
```

Note that if `get()` somehow *doesn't* return a Promise...I fear the solution will be something less straightforward.

Comment: this will serialize access to the db.  Using `Promise.all` would be another solution

Comment: Good point! I originally structured my approach to minimally alter the OP's code, but that could yield a more succinct approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, with it I'm getting "Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'". I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: @Tino Ah, I see - my mistake, I was using `await` but the callback function for the forEach was not async. I've ultimately taken Garr's suggestion and have used Promise.all() in my solution. Let me know if you continue to have problems!

Comment: Great solution, just a note, if `get()` doesn't return a Promise, we just wrap that with a function which returns a promise, and resolve inside callback (*promisify*) :) So not too complicated

Comment: @Serlite Thanks again for the suggestion! With it I'm getting "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: snapshot.map is not a function" on the console, I believe this is because Firebase stores data as objects instead of arrays. Is there a way that I could get around this?

Comment: @Tino I feel like we're so close - based on the [Firebase reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot?authuser=0#docs), I've updated it to map snapshot.docs instead of snapshot directly. Does that help?

Comment: @Serlite Thanks again! Now I get: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Comment: @Tino Interesting, that would suggest snapshot.docs wasn't set, though I don't know enough about Firebase to explain it. Can you try logging the value of snapshot and see what's in that variable? If it's something expected then you can just use snapshot.docs?.map(), but if not then maybe more fixes are needed.

Comment: @Tino Alternatively, perhaps snapshot.val().map() may give you more success - keep me posted! We may ultimately have to resort to [converting the firebase object into an array](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2017/05/convert-firebase-database-snapshotcollection-array-javascript/).

Comment: @Serlite Tried these and others things for a few hours today to no avail, going to take a break. Posted an update with new context I learned, any idea where I could go next from here? Best,

Comment: @Tino Hmm. I updated my answer to show how you might adapt my original solution to cast to an Array instead of using `snapshot.docs` - maybe give it a shot if your last attempts didn't include that already? Your latest edit to your question (which skips all this async/await stuff) is possibly rendering nothing because it doesn't wait for the Promises to resolve before rendering, though your logging suggests otherwise so I'm unsure.

Comment: @Serlite Thank you for your posting your update on converting the snapshot to array, seems I was doing it wrong when I tried on my own earlier. The conversion is working now, but further down the code on the `child.forEach((grandchild)` function , I am now getting this error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: child.forEach is not a function`.

Replacing `child` with `snapshot` shows me a glimpse of the closest I've gotten yet, so it got me exited, think it's almost there!! [This ends up with the values jumbled obviosuly](https://i.imgur.com/rCqZ8uG.png)

Comment: @Tino One last edit, and maybe we're there - I've altered the conversion function to return an array of the child snapshots, rather than pre-emptively calling .val()/.key on them. This way, the `forEach()` function should still be available on them since they'll still be Firebase objects.

Comment: @Serlite Yup, that did it. You're a god, seriously thank you so much for this and your time. Means a whole lot. Going to study your solution further so I can learn everything that I can from it. <3 <3